# JRuby Debugger Options with simple text editor

Tags: debugging, jruby

I am developing JRuby on textmate, do I have any debugger options?

At the moment I am using puts which is painstaking and drawn out.

Is there anyway, I can break during running code in the terminal and check values there?

Answer (score 0):

ruby-debug was the answer, I did need to install it via bundler though.